# Average Distance of a Point in a Circle from a Fixed Point Using Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus

What is the average distance of a point on a circle of radius a from a fixed point
Q on the circle? (Place the circle so Q is at the origin and use polar coordinates.)

Let $r = 2a \cos θ$, for $−π/2 < θ < π/2$. Since the upper and lower semicircles are symmetric, it suffices to calculate the average over the upper semicircle.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  The first paragraph looks like a homework problem, and the second looks like a hint.  What are your thoughts on the solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}2a \cos \theta \,d\theta}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}d\theta} =$$ 
 $$\frac{[2a \sin \theta]_0^{\frac{\pi}2}}{\frac{\pi}2} =$$
 $${\frac{4a}\pi} $$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

As described we need to evaluate

$$\frac{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}2a \cos \theta \,d\theta}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}d\theta}$$

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: It helps that the hints in this question set up the coordinates so that the length of an arc of the circle is proportional to $\Delta \theta.$ Therefore the average over the angle $\theta$ is also the average over the length of the circumference.